# Where's the code that handles the 'text-changed::insert' signal in Gtk?

Tags: gtk, signals, gtk3, gnome

I'm trying to trace some code in Gtk. I've got to this part in [gtkentryaccessible.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/b894c350080f5686a7c8bb7107001373da097b5f/gtk/a11y/gtkentryaccessible.c#L1392-L1395):

```
g_signal_emit_by_name (accessible,
                       "text-changed::insert",
                       *position - length,
                        length);
```

But I can't find the callback for the `text-changed::insert` signal.

I've tried Google-ing and I've cloned the git repo for the code and tried grepping for the signal name (with and without the `insert` detail) and for all callbacks with `text` or `changed` in the name, but nothing.

How can I find the code that handles the emit of this signal?

Comment: This is the signal emission. Maybe i'm not getting your question.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the comment. I understand that's the signal emission. My question is basically: where can I find the code that handles the signal emission? The code that is connected to that signal.

Comment: You must create it with g_signal_connect, that code just gets a signal emitted, then you attach a callback to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The comments from **@José** made me realise how badly worded this question is, so to clarify...

I have a very simple c progam that makes the following call:

```
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry), "thisisthetext");
```

I was trying to trace how this line results in the text actually being updated in the control - likely all the way into the source code of X.

So, I followed the call...

- According to [gtkentry.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/b894c350080f5686a7c8bb7107001373da097b5f/gtk/gtkentry.c#L7151-L7155), `gtk_entry_set_text` actually calls `gtk_editable_delete_text` followed by `gtk_editable_insert_text`.
- Then, according to [gtkeditable.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/b894c350080f5686a7c8bb7107001373da097b5f/gtk/gtkeditable.c#L211), `gtk_editable_insert_text` calls `do_insert_text`.
- And so on...

I followed it *incorrectly* and ended up at the `g_signal_emit_by_name(...)` function in the question. So I was confused as to how that function was called. The answer is of course that it isn't.

This question is no longer necessary. I've got as far as the text being inserted into the btree, still in gtk code, specifically [gtktextbuffer.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/4724a89022ef1bec93b1a42d4cf2fec7191ed712/gtk/gtktextbuffer.c#L900-L917):

```
_gtk_text_btree_insert (iter, text, len);
```